# Listview action and main action activity action bar appears at same time

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar

I am new to android, in my application I have navigation drawer,custom action bar and fragments to display context

In fragment I have multichoice listview, when I long select list view then contexutal action bar appears on top of screen, so both action bar are displayed main action bar and list view action.

Can some one please suggest :
1. when long selection list view then main menu actionbar should be hidden
2. OR atleast listview action come over main action bar.

Thanks
Sonu Kumar

Comment: you can get actionbar using getActionBar or getSupportActionbar inside your activity and call hide() on it right ?

Answer (score 0):

As you've a customized actionbar, edit your `style.xml` by adding  the following tags:

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

and make sure your style has parent theme of type `NoActionBar`.
For ex :  `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`